# Auto hide applications menu in kde

Tags: gnome, kubuntu, kde, appmenu, autohide

Lately there are some applications that have the option of hiding the menu and making it visible againg pressing alt, like sublime text, visual studio code, firefox, etc

Is there some plugin to make this behavior available for every app in kubuntu? It would be pretty useful ...

And for gnome? It would also be useful for those app that still haven't integrated the menu in the title bar...

Comment: firefox works the same way on gnome. I suspect that those that don't would just have that menu be permanently visible.

Comment: Part of the problem is that Linux often uses software made by independent contributors without specific requirements being forced on them. All the same, some applications in Kubuntu such as Dolphin, Gwenview, and Kate can toggle the menu bar using `Ctrl+M`.